# how do i connect to SQL server in SQL Server Mgmt Studio with SSPI Integrated Security

Tags: sql-server, sspi

i have an asp.net web app that has this in the web.config file in the project

```
server=[server],15001;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=DB_NAME
```

how do i connect to this database from Sql server mgmt studio since there is not use or password in the connection string.  i am connecting from a remote machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you connect using "Integrated Security", it uses the current Windows credentials of the process - in the case of connecting to SSMS, it will use your current Windows user. If your Windows user has rights to the SQL Server, then you can connect using Intergrated Security.

If you need to connect to the SQL Server using Integrated Security, but as another user, you'll need to do a "Run As..." on SSMS to load it as the different user.